# What is the performance of 10 processors capable of 200 MFLOPs running code which is 10% sequential and 90% parallelelizable?

Tags: performance, parallel-processing

simple problem from Wilkinson and Allen's Parallel Programming: Techniques and Applications Using Networked Workstations and Parallel Computers. Working through the exercises at the end of the first chapter and want to make sure that I'm on the right track. The full question is:

**1-11** *A multiprocessor consists of 10 processors, each capable of a peak execution rate of 200 MFLOPs (millions of floating point operations per second). What is the performance of the system as measured in MFLOPs when 10% of the code is sequential and 90% is parallelizable?*

I assume the question wants me to find the number of operations per second of a serial processor which would take the same amount of time to run the program as the multiprocessor.

I think I'm right in thinking that 10% of the program is run at 200 MFLOPs, and 90% is run at 2,000 MFLOPs, and that I can average these speeds to find the performance of the multiprocessor in MFLOPs:

```
1/10 * 200 + 9/10 * 2000 = 1820 MFLOPs
```

So when running a program which is 10% serial and 90% parallelizable the performance of the multiprocessor is 1820 MFLOPs.

Is my approach correct?

ps: I understand that this isn't exactly how this would work in reality because it's far more complex, but I would like to know if I'm grasping the concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation would be fine if 90% of the time, all 10 processors were fully utilized, and 10% of the time, just 1 processor was in use. However, I don't think that is a reasonable interpretation of the problem. I think it is more reasonable to assume that if a single processor were used, 10% of its computations would be on the sequential part, and 90% of its computations would be on the parallelizable part.

One possibility is that the sequential part and parallelizable parts can be run in parallel. Then one processor could run the sequential part, and the other 9 processors could do the parallelizable part. All processors would be fully used, and the result would be 2000 MFLOPS.

Another possibility is that the sequential part needs to be run first, and then the parallelizable part. If a single processor needed 1 hour to do the first part, and 9 hours to do the second, then it would take 10 processors 1 + 0.9 = 1.9 hours total, for an average of about (1*200 + 0.9*2000)/1.9 ~ 1053 MFLOPS.